# How to get hold of the current NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration instance

Tags: c#, nhibernate

My C# project has repositories that are instantiated using dependency injection.

One of the repository methods needs access to the `NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration` instance (to generate the database schema) that was returned when initializing NHibernate.

I cannot pass the configuration to the repository however, because that would break the persistence ignorance principle -- I really don't want to expose any implementation details through the repository interface.

So what I'm looking for is a way of getting hold of the current `NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration` instance from within my repository. I have no trouble getting hold of the current session, it's just the configuration that I cannot get hold of.

Comment: IMHO generating the schema isn't one of the responsibilities of a repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. The SessionFactory does not keep any references to the Configuration that built it.

Anyway, as Mauricio said: schema generation is not a Repository concern.